# Orca system error: orca(fig,"my_file.pdf") Error in processx::run("orca", "-h") : System command error

Tags: plotly, anaconda3, orca

### I tried to use the orca() function in the plotly package, but after installing the command line utility of orca using  the following command:

> conda create -n my_root --clone="/usr/local/anaconda3"

### it says

Source:      /usr/local/anaconda3
Destination: /home/trg710/.conda/envs/my_root
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:

- conda-env-2.6.0-h36134e3_1
- conda-4.3.27-py36h2866c0b_0
- conda-build-3.0.23-py36h1da9bb0_0
  Packages: 232
  Files: 0

To activate this environment, use:

> source activate my_root

To deactivate an active environment, use:

> source deactivate

### Then I enter

> source /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/activate my_root
> conda install -c plotly plotly-orca

### Output on the screen

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
plotly-orca: 1.3.1-1 plotly
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

### Once it's successfully installed, I ran the R command orca() and got the following error.

> orca(fig,"my_file.pdf")
> Error in processx::run("orca", "-h") : System command error.

### Not sure how to proceed. I couldn't find any resolved comments on this platform. If anyone could help that'd be great.

Thanks,
LOH